# Converting pagination from `react-js-pagination` to` react-bootstrap` pagination

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination, react-bootstrap

I have a ready pagination component: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-js-pagination

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Pagination from "react-js-pagination";
require("bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less");

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      activePage: 1,
      todos: []
    };
  }

  handlePageChange(pageNumber) {
    console.log(`active page is ${pageNumber}`);
    this.setState({activePage: pageNumber});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Pagination
          activePage={this.state.activePage}
          totalItemsCount={this.state.todos.length}
          pageRangeDisplayed={2}
          onChange={this.handlePageChange}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

How to transform pagination from `react-js-pagination` to`react-bootstrap` pagination https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/pagination/  ?

Comment: You have all the information you need in the links you provided to do this conversion yourself. If you're stuck on a specific problem related to it, you need to be more clear. What exactly have you tried so far? What errors or behavior are you seeing? StackOverflow does not exist to simply write your code for you. Try doing it yourself first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`react-bootstrap` pagination is just a UI component that renders the pagination items and can't handle the stuff `react-js-pagination` is handling. It is mentioned in `react-js-pagination` docs that you can import your own CSS style and use the classes for the pagination items. So just importing `bootstrap` style is enough and then you can do this:

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

<ReactPagination
    itemClass="page-item"
    linkClass="page-link"
    hideNavigation
    activePage={2}
    itemsCountPerPage={10}
    totalItemsCount={450}
    pageRangeDisplayed={5}
/>
```

Check this Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-darkness-pm7v8?fontsize=14

Answer (score 0):

I use the react-bhx-pagination because you can get the json, auto load when you get to the end of the page and it's very easy to use and change.

Example: [Online demo](https://react-bhx-pagination.netlify.app/)

Component:
[react-bhx-pagination](https://github.com/coffezilla/react-bhx-pagination)